# TypeScript interface naming conventions & declaration merging

Tags: typescript

If each React component is in a different file should the Props (or State) interface of a React component have a unique name, and does it matter?  If each component is in a separate files does declaration merging apply?

I argue all Props should be prefixed with the component name e.g. `SelectProps` and not just `Props`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your are using export/import when declaring/consuming your react components. If this is the case then - declaration merging does not apply (see module augmentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)). And even in case if you don't - declaration merging still [will not apply](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3802).

Normally you would like to export properties as they are publicly available for other components to use - and therefore it is a good idea to give them names that would allow them to be easily identified and imported without aliasing. On the other hand component states that are not exported you can technically make to be named the same - although I strongly do not recommend doing so - in practice during development you will find it hard to search for some particular state/props if they are all named the same.